# How to encode NSString to Euc-kr

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring

I'm struggling with encoding a `NSString` variable to Euc-kr type... :(
The DB server I have to communicate is based on Euc-kr so I have no choice but to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer is nearly right, but as EUC-KR is not an NSString encoding, you first have to get the encoding from CF land. Something like this:

```
NSUInteger encoding = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingEUC_KR);
const char * eucKRString = [string cStringUsingEncoding:encoding];
```

Comment: Wow. what a way around to do it... Thank you